# A way to find out which sites of my websites are indexed

Tags: seo, google-search, google-index

Is there any way to find out which urls of my websites are indexed and which not?

(e.g. site:http://example.com/site1.html)

What i tried:

- Used google ajax api -> Problem here is that the results are totally different from the ones i'm getting from the google search
- Used google custom search api -> Same problem here: The results differ from the ones google is showing (because its actually kind of like a private search)
- Used Jsoup to crawl google -> Since its against there Terms its really hard to do -> I set a timeout between every request (between 30s-90s) and used proxies. Still i can't crawl for a long time and google blocks the ip.

What to do? :)

Comment: Register for [Google Webmaster Tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/#?modal_active=none)

Comment: Ya ok - but Google Webmaster won't tell you exactly which sites are not indexed - it just tells you that x amount of sites are not indexed.

Comment: Did you already take a look at the [Search Console API](https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/)? If you submit a sitemap and make google know what you expect to be indexed you could identify missing pages from the crawl error list. Imho if you want to do SEO for google using their Search Console Tools is a must.